# Sources of information about postdoctoral/PhD grants and funding

Tags: postdocs, funding

We are a research group in Spain. For first year postdocs and PhDs from other european countries that want to come to our lab, there is no support for spanish ministry of science. Therefore we wonder where can we find information about such funding from any other country in the world.

Comment: This is a good idea, but I fear that the directory would be quite large and quickly go out of date. We have a department that produces an online directory of all the funding opportunities available at all levels, across all departments. It covers everything from travel grants to multi-million euro EU projects. There are many many opportunities. Maintaining such a list across countries would be difficult.

Comment: could we acccess your online directory?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is only accessible to staff and only in Dutch.

Comment: _it is to our advantage to avoid encouraging competition_ — [citation needed]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As a PhD student trying to find a good postdoc position it's in my interest to help you find funding for places. These links may help as they all currently have open calls for projects/fellowship funding:

- Google Awards http://research.google.com/university/relations/research_awards.html
- Marie-Curie Actions http://ec.europa.eu/research/mariecurieactions/
- ERCIM https://fellowship.ercim.eu/

Please let me know if you manage to get some funding ;)